# Android studio speed

Tags: android-studio

Android studio was working fine when I haven't updated my windows but when I updated my windows 10 pro to latest Android studio become slow it takes app.2 min to load and build sync.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Go to your local store and buy a new PC

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your window. Buy or upgrade your PC.